# faster and more 'pythonic' list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

For simplicity, I've provided 2 lists in a list, but I'm actually dealing with a hundred of lists in a list, each containing a sizable amount of dictionaries. I only want to get the value of 'status' key in the 1st dictionary without checking any other dictionaries in that list (since I know they all contain the same value at that key). Then I will perform some sort of clustering within each big dictionary. I need to efficiently concatenate all 'title' values. Is there a way to make my code more elegant and much faster?

I have:

```
nested = [
    [
        {'id': 287, 'title': 'hungry badger',  'status': 'High'},
        {'id': 437, 'title': 'roadtrip to Kansas','status': 'High'}
    ],
    [
        {'id': 456, 'title': 'happy title here','status': 'Medium'},
        {'id': 342,'title': 'soft big bear','status': 'Medium'}
    ]
]
```

I'd like:

```
result = [
    {
        'High': [
            {'id': 287, 'title': 'hungry badger'},
            {'id': 437, 'title': 'roadtrip to Kansas'}
        ]
    },
    {
        'Medium': [
            {'id': 456, 'title': 'happy title here'},
            {'id': 342, 'title': 'soft big bear'}
        ]
    }
]
```

What I tried:

```
for oneList in nested: 
   result= {}
   for i in oneList:        
       a= list(i.keys()) 
       m= [i[key] for key in a if key not in ['id','title']]
       result[m[0]]=oneList
       for key in a:
            if key not in ['id','title']:
                del i[key]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby    
result = groupby(sum(nested,[]), lambda x: x['status'])
```

How it works:

`sum(nested,[])` concatenates all your outer lists together into one big list of dictionaries

`groupby(, lambda x: x['status'])` groups all your objects by their status property

Note itertools.groupby returns a generator (not a list), so if you want to materialize the generator you need to do something like follows.

```
from itertools import groupby    
result = groupby(sum(nested,[]), lambda x: x['status'])
result = {key:list(val) for key,val in result}
```

Comment: omg! @.@  Wow. you are so fast with the solution. Thank you so very much!!!! Works perfectly.

Comment: One: Don't use `sum(nested, [])`, ever. It's the slowest possible way to flatten, and it gets slower the more you're flattening (it's creating `n` temporary `list`s, growing each time). You're already using `itertools`, and you're iterating the results (don't need a true `list` at all), so just use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten (and because `lambda` is evil/slow when not needed, `operator.itemgetter` for `key`): `groupby(chain.from_iterable(nested), itemgetter('status'))`. [`sum(x, [])` is _slow_ (see comments)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39520827/364696).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks man! Just ran this: from itertools import chain;
import operator; s= groupby(chain.from_iterable(results), key=operator.itemgetter('status'));
for key, grp in s: print(key, list(grp))  All good.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a `defaultdict` for each nested list:

```
import collections
nested = [
[{'id': 287, 'title': 'hungry badger',  'status': 'High'},
{'id': 437, 'title': 'roadtrip to Kansas','status': 'High'}],     
[{'id': 456, 'title': 'happy title here','status': 'Medium'},
{'id': 342,'title': 'soft big bear','status': 'Medium'}]   ]
result = []
for l in nested:
    r = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for d in l:
        name = d.pop('status')
        r[name].append(d)
    result.append(r)
```

This gives the following `result`:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
[{'High': [{'id': 287, 'title': 'hungry badger'},
           {'id': 437, 'title': 'roadtrip to Kansas'}]},
 {'Medium': [{'id': 456, 'title': 'happy title here'},
             {'id': 342, 'title': 'soft big bear'}]}]
```

Comment: Awesome. Tnx! Learning smth new on here every day. Hehe. That itertools' groupby solution is looking so good; reduces complexity. Your answer taught me about collections.defaultdict(). Thanks again.

Comment: oh nice! Ur solution removes status and does what i was asking. I gonna time both of these just for heck of it and also play a bit more with itertools' groupby... Thanks for help, man!